# Firebase useAuth() context in App.js is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, use-context

I have a AuthProvider and useAuth method that returns useContext(AuthContext) inside my App.js root file, however, if I console.log the return value of useAuth() in App.js, it is undefined, why??
In any other child component like Loginpage, there is an authContext displayed..

my App.js:

```
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from './providers/AuthProvider'
function App() {
    const auth = useAuth()
    console.log({ auth }) //undefined??
```

AuthProvider.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { app, auth, firestore, storage } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined)
    const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState(null)

    const login = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        } catch (error) {
            setLoginError(error)
        }
    }

    

    const logout = () => auth.signOut()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const value = {
        loginError,
        login,
        signup,
        logout,
        currentUser,
        app,
        firestore,
        storage,
        auth,
    }

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you import `AuthProvider` in same file of `App` it gives a clue that you didn't use the Context API correctly.

Context values are available for Context-Consumers.

Context-Consumers are children of Context-Provider, therefore your `App` component have to be a child of `<AuthContext.Provider>`:

```
<AuthProvider>
  <App />
</AuthProvider>
```

Comment: yup, that was exactly the reason. Alternatively, I could use a redirect programmatically in my component useEffect hook with `history.push(/)`...

Comment: can you maybe explain further why it did not work that way? Because I was wrapping the Provider in the top level of App.js nonetheless.. is it because I was importing Consumer in the app before the provider was rendered in the App.js itself?

Comment: As mentioned, it didnt work because you call `useContext` while the component calling the hook is not a consumer, its actually a provider. Anyway your example is not complete since you dont show the App render function.